# How to get chrome to run extensions automatically?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a chrome extensions. I've developed a few firefox extensions a few years ago. In firefox it was possible to automatically run your extension of the page, and alter the page's content (add HTML and style it). I'd like the extension to automatically change the html, without requiring the user to click a button up in the browser's window.
How to get chrome to run extensions automatically?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I guess you want to ask "how is it possible", that's why this is a comment.

Comment: I've not developed any extensions, but I am pretty sure that it is done through JavaScript, if so, it would be things like `document.getElementById('idname');` or even better, you should be able to inject jQuery, and just use jQuery to do whatever you want. If anything, you run it on pageload using $(function() {});

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to declare a content script in your manifest.json, it will be automatically executed on all pages matching the corresponding URL pattern without any user interaction.